# Error while updating to Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem while trying to update to Firebase real time database.
I'm getting the error "`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead`

I think this might mean I need to use another way to update the data since I'm using a recyclerView instead of a listView, but since now I have:

```
 public void update_button(){
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            snapshot.getRef().child("title").setValue(postTitleEdit.getText());
            snapshot.getRef().child("desc").setValue(postTextEdit.getText());
            Toast.makeText(CowDet.this, "updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            CowDet.this.finish();

        }
```

The way I'm using to add data to firebase is:

```
mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            Blog blog = snapshot.getValue(Blog.class);
            blogList.add(blog);
            blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(PostListActivity.this, blogList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);
            blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Could someone help me update the data? I'm kinda stuck here.

Here is my Blog class:

```
public class Blog {
public String title;
public String desc;
public String image;
public String timestamp;
public String userid;


public Blog() {
}

public Blog(String title, String desc, String image, String timestamp, String userid, String milkQty, String note) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.image = image;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.userid = userid;

}

public Blog(String title, String desc) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.image = image;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.userid = userid;
}

public Blog(String toString) {

}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}
```

}

new update_button

```
  public void update_button(){

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            databaseReference.child("Mblog").child("title").setValue(postTitleEdit);
           
            Toast.makeText(CowDet.this, "updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            CowDet.this.finish();

        }
```

new error: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getText
I'm getting this error on the line `databaseReference.child("Mblog").child("title").setValue(postTitleEdit);`

Comment: I tried to answer below, but it'll be easier to help if you ensure your question includes a so-called [minimal, complete/standalone example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which any of us can reproduce the problem. That would include all necessary code, data, and the complete stack trace of the error you get.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I've added my Blog class but I don't have any [] array

Comment: Then maybe the error comes from somewhere else. Can you edit the question to show the entire stack trace?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've change a little the way I was updating and now I'm getting the error com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getText, I've updated the question, at the end is the new error

Comment: That's a different error, so a different question. But please seaarch for the error message first, as it's been covered multiple times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty explicit. Your `Blog` class seems to contain an array (with `[]`), which isn't supported by Firebase's serializer. You should instead use a `List` class for the same purpose.

If you're having a hard time making that work, edit your question to include the `Blog` class.